# Получение данных нескольких типов постов из БД

Tags: wordpress

Нужно получить количество страниц произвольных таксономий, при использовании данного кода получается получить данные только для одного типа, можно как то получать данные сразу по нескольким типам постов?

```
function get_totalpages() {
    global $wpdb;
    // Есть несколько типов постов my_tape_1, my_tape_2, my_tape_3
    $totalpages = intval( $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'my-tape_1' AND post_status = 'publish'"
    ));

    return $totalpages;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```
function get_totalpages() {
    global $wpdb;
    // Есть несколько типов постов my_tape_1, my_tape_2, my_tape_3
    
    $post_types = ['my_tape_1', 'my_tape_2', 'my_tape_3'];
    
    $totalpages = intval( $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type IN ('".implode("','", $post_types)."') AND post_status = 'publish'"
    ));

    return $totalpages;
}
```